# Impossible to obtain Type tokens from Class objects?

Tags: java, generics, syntactic-sugar

Let's say I have a generic interface that is implemented by various classes.

```java
public interface MyInterface<K, V> {
    // Some method declarations
    // ...
    // But owing to Java type erasure, we also have...
    Class<K> getKClass();
    Class<V> getVClass();
}
```

Now, I'm using an object store to obtain concrete instances of classes that implement `MyInterface`. And I don't know at the time of writing the code the types of parameters `K` and `V`. But, it's possible to access the corresponding `Class` objects that were stored in advance. Now I could use them while requesting the factory.

```java
public MyInterface getObjectFromStore(String uniqueKey, 
      Class kClazz, Class vClazz) {
    MyInterface concreteInstance = MyClassWarehouse.retrieveObject(uniqueKey);

    // Perform type checks.
    boolean kMismatch = !kClazz.isAssignableFrom(concreteInstance.getKClass());
    boolean vMismatch = ...;
    // Mismatch handling...
    ...

    // Everything's okay
    return concreteInstance;
}
```

It seems to me that the code would look much cleaner if I could write my method as:

```java
public <K, V> MyInterface<K, V> getObjectFromStore(String uniqueKey) {
    try {
        MyInterface<K, V> concreteInstance = MyClassWarehouse.retrieveObject(uniqueKey);
        return concreteInstance;
    } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
        // Better way to handle type mismatch
        ...
    }
}
```

But this requires that I know the classes at the time of writing the code.

```java
MyInterface<String, Double> retrievedObject = getObjectFromStore("key123");
```

Since I only have class objects, I must use the first, "clumsier" approach. In particular:

```java
// Must use this...
MyInterface retrievedObject = getObjectFromStore("key123", kClazz, vClazz);

// ... because this (or anything equivalent) is not possible.
MyInterface<kClazz, vClazz> retrievedObject = getObjectFromStore("key123");
```

It seems to me that since types are not bonafide objects in Java, there's no way of obtaining type tokens `K` and `V` from class objects `kClazz` and `vClazz` in a manner that would enable the second approach. However, syntactic sugar would be nice.

Is there another reason for this to not be enabled?

Comment: On this line  MyInterface<K, V> concreteInstance = MyClassWarehouse.retrieveObject(uniqueKey); does retriveObject method return a object that is implemented by MyInterface with your type tokens respectively?

Comment: It ought to. `MyClassWarehouse` is dedicated to storing objects of (the various) classes that implement `MyInterface`. However, at the time of retrieving objects, I'd like to ensure type consistency.

Comment: The clumsier code also uses raw types, which is kinda beyond clumsy.

Answer (score 1):

If you are throwing away compile-time checking in favour of runtime checking, you are going to need runtime type objects from two sources in order to do any comparisons.

So, yup the simplest is specifying `Class` object both ends. In the simple case.

```
<T> void put(Class<T> t, T object);
<T> T get(Class<T> t);
```

Adding a specific double parameterised type (no higher-kinded types in Java), the two types and a key (boo to stringy programming).

```
<K,V> void put(Class<K> k, Class<V> v, Key key, My<K,V> object);
<K,V> My<K,V> get(Class<K> k, Class<V> v, Key key);
```

There's an opportunity to combine the three key objects into one.

```
public final class MyKey<K,V> {
    public static of(Class<K> k, Class<V> v, SimpleKey key) {
        ....
    }
    ...
}
<K,V> void put(MyKey<K,V> key, My<K,V> object);
<K,V> My<K,V> get(MyKey<K,V> key);
```

Alternatively, you can look for a different source of class objects. They are available from method signatures.

```
public interface MyReceiver<K,V> {
    void accept(My<K,V> object);
}
/** @param receiver Runtime type should specialise type parameters. */    
void get(MyReceiver<?,?> receiver);
```

(`MyReciever<?,?>` could be a standard `Consumer<? extends MyReciever<?,?>>`.)

You can add an additional simple key as either a parameter to `get` (lambda friendly), a method on `MyReceiver`, an annotation on `accept` or `MyReceiver`, or drop the method from `MyReceiver` and use whatever they runtime type uses as a method name (perhaps annotated to find which method you want).

In fact this approach of **specifying required types in interfaces is rather more modern than old school heterogeneous maps**.

(Note also the "repository" is the standard term for your warehouse.)

Comment: I need a little while to unpack everything you've said here. I will get back on this.